# What are Stein's bounds for multivariate distributions?

Tags: pr.probability

Stein's bound in the total variation distance
$d_{TV}$ expresses that if $F$ is an integrable real random variable, and $N$ a
random variable with the standard normal distribution $\mathcal {N}(0,1)$, then
$$
    d_{TV} (F, N) \leq \sup | E(f'(F)) - E (F f(F)) | 
$$
where the supremum runs over the smooth (absolutely continuous)
functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such
that $\| f\|_\infty \leq \sqrt {\frac \pi 2}$ and $\| f'\|_\infty \leq 2$
([cf. Nourdin-Peccati, 2012, Chapter~3](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2962301)). A similar bound holds for the
Wasserstein distance $W_1$ with the class of functions $f$ satisfying
$\| f'\|_\infty \leq \sqrt {\frac 2\pi}$.

What would be a version of this bound (in total variation or Wasserstein distance)
for $F$ and $N$ random vectors in $\mathbb {R}^d$ ($N$ with the standard normal law
with mean zero and covariance matrix the identity)?

Answer (score 1):

See e.g. [Stein's method for functions of multivariate normal random variables](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.08688), in particular, formula (1.3) there:
\begin{equation} \nabla^T\Sigma\nabla f(\mathbf{w})-\mathbf{w}^T\nabla f(\mathbf{w})=h(\mathbf{w})-Eh(\Sigma^{1/2}\mathbf{Z}),
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{Z}$ denotes a random vector having the standard multivariate normal distribution of dimension $d$. See also further references in that paper.

In the case when each coordinate of a random vector $F=(F_1,\dots,F_d)$ in $\mathbb R^d$ is a certain kind of limit (defined at the bottom of p. 47 of [Multivariate normal approximation using Stein's method and Malliavin calculus by Nourdin, Peccati, and Réveillac](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aihp/1267454107)) of certain smooth cylindrical functionals of an isonormal Gaussian process (indexed by elements of a Hilbert space) , Theorem 3.5 of that paper provides an upper bound on the Wasserstein distance between the distribution of $f$ and a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: I cannot find in the paper (and the references therein) any inequality, in total variation or Wasserstein, that looks like the one-dimensional bounds?

Comment: @RebeccaLuke : I have added another reference.

Comment: Thank you, but this is of course very specific, and not as general and useful as the one-dimensional case.

Comment: @RebeccaLuke : I don't think this is very specific. Say, in Proposition 4..3 of the 2nd linked paper (which is a corollary of Theorem 3.5 of that paper), each of the coordinates of the random vector $W$ can have any distribution with not too heavy tails. Apparently, quite a bit more can be said here, using (say) Monge transport functions to transport a multivariate normal distribution to a rather general multivariate distribution (but I have not considered this in details).

Comment: The coordinates $W_i$ are (smooth) functions of a given Gaussian vector...